# Причина появления в Android Studio null ошибки

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня иногда студия может выводить такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем может быть причина? Вроде как на производительность это не очень влияет (пока во всяком случае), но тем не менее хотелось-бы узнать причины.

Comment: В какой момент возникает ошибка, либо при каком коде?

Comment: честно говоря, у меня появилось впечатление что эта ошибка возникает просто так. Я могу сидеть и работать и тут она неожиданно возникает, не спорю что возможно в следствии моих действий, но я ничего запрещенного не делал.

Comment: вот сейчас я просто открыл другой проект, и у меня опять выскочила эта ошибка.

Comment: AS как и любой софт, содержит баги. Если это не мешает работать, не обращайте внимание.

Comment: а ну ок, а то я думал может какие-то проблемы уже лезут

Comment: Что интересно я гуглю "android studio fatal error null", нахожу вопросы на enSO но они удалены :)

Comment: вот я вроде сейчас работаю, перехожу в студии между файлами, и эта ошибка может иногда появляться) странная система)